# Using Selenium in docker container

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium in a docker container but I got the error below. To me it seems the selenium image is not linked to the webapp image but I couldn't resolve this.

Here is the **DockerFile**

```
# Use a Python base image
FROM python:3.10-alpine


# Install Selenium
RUN pip install selenium


RUN mkdir /app

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python script into the container
COPY test.py /app/
```

Here is the **Docker-compose file**

```
version: '3'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    restart: always
    shm_size: 2g

  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: sh -c "python3 test.py"
    depends_on:
      - selenium
```

Here is **test.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Wait for the Selenium Grid to be up and running
time.sleep(5)


# Initialize the Remote WebDriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://webapp:4444/wd/hub',
   options=chrome_options
)


# Navigate to Google
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Save a screenshot of the page
driver.save_screenshot('search_results.png')

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Here is the **Error message**

```
test-webapp-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
test-webapp-1    |   File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
test-webapp-1    |     driver = webdriver.Remote(
test-webapp-1    | urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='selenium', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f48af752160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
test-webapp-1 exited with code 1
```

**Additional note**
It runs on locally if I replace `command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub'` in the `test.py` with `command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'`.

Comment: Replace `command_executor` in `test.py` with `http://webapp:4444/wd/hub` to resolve connection issues between `webapp` and `selenium` containers. Make sure both containers are on the same network and wait until the `selenium` container is fully initialized before the `webapp` container is started.

Comment: I updated the `test.py` as you mentioned but I still got the same issue. How do I wait until the `selenium` container is fully initialized before the `webapp` container is started?

Comment: To wait until the Selenium container is fully initialized before the webapp container starts, you can add the `depends_on` option to the webapp service in your Docker Compose. This option ensures that the webapp container will not be started until the container described in `depends_on` has also been started.

Comment: @aazizzailani Could you help test locally? I have tried different approaches but to no avail. I have updated the current state of the files.